# Are swapped in hot-swap drives allocated the same Windows drive letter each time?

Tags: windows-server-2008, hotswap

We are intending on purchasing a dedicated machine to perform the company's backups.  We were considering buying the Dell T310, with the theory that we could swap the drives in and out for offsite backup.  (As in, take out a drive, put a version a couple of days' old in its place, the old backup is updated to the current version.)

One thing that may stymie this, though, is the system changing drive letters as things get moved in and out.

Does anyone know whether this happens?

Comment: Before making your decision final may I suggest you have a good read of the numerous posts, both here and elsewhere regarding the use of hard drives as a backup medium, and the many reasons why it's a bad idea. In short, hard drives are fragile and should be viewed as temporary at best.

Comment: IF you are dead-set on HD backups at least consider getting something with HD cases designed regular swapping.  For example high-rely.com has some interesting looking devices, specifically designed for HD backups.  http://high-rely.com/HR3/includes/HighRely/2BayTandem/2BayTandem.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Server 2008 writes a GUID to each drive and remembers the settings for that drive. If you assign them all the same letter, then they'll keep that letter. When you put a new drive in and format it, it might get a different letter, depends on your exact configuration (though this shouldn't really be a problem, as you can just change the letter).